# The linearization at an equilibrium point of a planar Hamiltonian system has eigenvalues that are either +-a or +-ai, a in R

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a proposition in our textbook, but it is never explained as to why (we take it as given), and it doesn't seem very intuitive.  Is there an elegant way to show this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A planar Hamiltonian system looks like

$\dot q = \dfrac{\partial H(p, q)}{\partial p} = H_p, \tag 1$

$\dot p = -\dfrac{\partial H(p, q)}{\partial q} = -H_q. \tag 2$

The Jacobean matrix $J_H$ of (1)-(2) is

$J_H = \begin{bmatrix} H_{pq} & H_{pp} \\ -H_{qq} & -H_{qp} \end{bmatrix}. \tag 3$

If we allow that

$H \in C^2(U, \Bbb R), \tag 4$

where $U \subset \Bbb R^2$ is an open set on which $H(p, q)$ is defined, then

$H_{pq} = H_{qp}, \tag 5$

so it follows that the trace of $J_H$,

$\text{Tr}(J_H) = H_{pq} - H_{qp} = 0; \tag 6$

thus the characteristic polynomial $\chi_H(\lambda)$ of $J_H$ is easily seen to be

$\chi_H(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - \text{Tr}(J_H) \lambda + \det(J_H) = \lambda^2 + \det(J_H) = 0; \tag 7$

it follows that

$\det(J_H) \le 0 \Longrightarrow \lambda =\pm \sqrt {-\det(J_H)} \in \Bbb R,\tag 8$

and

$\det(J_H) > 0 \Longrightarrow \lambda =\pm i\sqrt {\det(J_H)} \in i\Bbb R, \tag 9$

as per request. $OE\Delta$